# Material-UI: How to make aligned form

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material-UI. How does one typically build a form, where some fields are grouped horizontally while others are stacked vertically and all the fields aligns nicely both vertically and horizontally? See the following example picture:

[image]

I know how to build this kind of form with plain HTML tables, but what is the "correct" Material-UI way? Example code would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a sample for the first two rows:

```js
<form>
<Grid container>
  <Grid item xs="12">
    <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>

<Grid container>
  <Grid item xs="8">
    <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard"/>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs="4">
    <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
</form>
```